# Cant submit apps facebook's approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Trying to submit Android apps for Facebook's approval before we submit to Play Store. Our apps were created by third party and we would like to transfer the apps to our FB account before we submit to FB.

So we created a new FB account. But FB keeps on blocking the account with following reason "Someone may have accessed your account" and disabling our apps.

It's been a week and no response the the support team. Can anyone help us? Or removing Facebook integration from the app is the best option here?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you managing apps via a real Facebook account? i.e. your personal account? Facebook requires developers use their real accounts to create and manage apps. If you use a fake account, and that account gets determined to be fake, all the apps associated with it will be disabled.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Don't have a personal FB account. So created a new one. Can't a new account submit apps?

Comment: Facebook's systems likely see new accounts with no friends creating lots of apps as pretty suspicious. I recommend building up a real Facebook account.